# Quick command-line FTP server?

Tags: ftp

With newer PHP command line, I have a "quick" HTTP server - I simply go to a directory, and issue:

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

... and then that directory becomes "root" of a "webserver filesystem" being served on `http://localhost:8000`.

Is there something similar for FTP? I don't need a full blown FTP server, so for this kind of temporary purpose I find the setup of the usual FTP daemons a bit too complex. I'd just like to go to a directory, issue something like the pseudocode:

```
ftpMYserver -u testuser -p testpass localhost:21
```

... which also sets up a test user and password. Then, I could use say `lftp` like:

```
lftp -u testuser localhost
```

... and hopefully be able to GET and PUT files to the directory "ftpMYserver" is running in.

Is there some sort of a facility like that?

```
lftp -u testuser -p
```

Comment: Related discussion from SO for python options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994638/one-line-ftp-server-in-python

Comment: Wow, ftp.  Can you just use `scp` and/or `sftp` instead?